# Check existance of record with a specified value in CloudKit using swift

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I have a problem. I am doing an app that has login capabilities and would like to check if a user with a specified username exists. So I did:

```
func doesRecordExist(inRecordType: String, withField: String, equalTo: String) -> Bool {
    print(withField,equalTo)
    var result = false

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(withField) == %@", equalTo)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: inRecordType, predicate: predicate)
    publicDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil, completionHandler: {results, er in

        if results != nil {
            print(results!.count)
            if results?.count == 1 {
                print(results!.count)
                result = true
            }
        }
    })
    return result
}
```

where in withField "username" will be entered and in equalTo the value will be entered which is the username.

What did I do wrong? 
Thanks.

**Edit** 
Ok, I've finally figured out how to do what rmaddy suggesteed and it worked. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return a value from a function if that function's result depends on the result of an asynchronous action. As written, the `return result` line at the end of the function (with a value of `false`) will be called long before the database query is even started.

Your `doesRecordExist` function needs to use a completion handler parameter much line the `perform` function does.

Of course you will need to refactor your code that calls your `doesRecordExist` to deal with the fact that you will not get back an immediate result.

Comment: I don't have an experience with creating completion handlers, yet,  I can only handle them, so how should I do it?

Comment: It's been 2+ years so I assume you figured this out but I added a completion handler to your code so you can see it in separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code converted to add a completion handler as per rmaddy's response as this should let your code wait for a result before proceeding with the next code.

```
func doesRecordExist(inRecordType: String, withField: String, equalTo: String, _ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    print(withField,equalTo)
    var result = false

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(withField) == %@", equalTo)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: inRecordType, predicate: predicate)
    publicDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil, completionHandler: {results, er in

        if results != nil {
            print(results!.count)
            if results?.count == 1 {
                print(results!.count)
                result = true
            }
        }
    })
    completion(result)
}
```

Then you run your code elsewhere as:

```
doesRecordExist(inRecordType: String, withField: String, equalTo: String) { (result) in
                    if result == false {
                   //create new record here
                    }
                }
```